# Times Opening Curly Bracket: Remove the initial horizontal skip

Tags: spacing, unicode, braces

I would like the opening curly brackets in *Times* to start against the margin.

How can I create a "fixed" curly bracket?

```
 \documentclass{article}
 
 \usepackage{fontspec}
    
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

    
\begin{document}


\noindent Lines start against the margin.

\noindent Other lines start against the margin.

\noindent \{Opening cruly brackets are not positioned against the margin.\}

\noindent \kern0.75pt\!\{Removing glue and adding a 0.75pt kern is the only fix I can think of.\}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding an example for illustrating the issue inside a paragraph :

```
\documentclass{article}
 
 \usepackage{fontspec}
    
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newcommand{\bracel}{%
  \leavevmode
  \kern-0.1em
  \{%
}

\newcommand{\tslt}[1]{\unskip\space`#1'}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexAUX}{mmm}{\textit{#1}\IfNoValueF{#2}{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}\IfNoValueF{#3}{\tslt{#3}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lex}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{\lexAUX#1}

\newcommand{\unor}[2]{\bracel\lex{#1}\kern3pt\char"2194\kern3pt\lex{#2}\}}
    
\begin{document}


Morpheme-based lexicalism must not posit a root illude. Instead it tries to account for the fact that all \textit{-ion} and \textit{-ive} Ns have a meaning retrievable from the corresponding V, when it is attested. “allowing a direct relationship” is unfortunate..ly an ad-hoc solution: why should a direct relationship be posited, while when the V is attested as in e.g.\@ attract attraction attractive, suggest suggestion suggestive,  prohibit prohibition prohibitive (all from example (3.32) in Haspelmath and Sims 2010, the V is supposed to be the common ancestor : \unor{attraction,n}{attractive,a}, \unor{suggestion,n}{suggestive,a}, \unor{prohibition,n}{prohibitive,a}.



\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there are any glue/kerning on a symbol like that. Have you tried `{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\{}}` just to see what size the symbol is seen from the LaTeX side. In some fonts this size might not be what one expects.

Comment: I have just tried your line and there is still the little space before it inside the box. If I use \! before the bracket then the space disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font designer decided that the left brace should have a wide left sidebearing.

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{fontspec}
    
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont=TeX Gyre Termes,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]

\newcommand{\bracel}{\hspace*{-0.1em}\{}

\newcommand{\tslt}[1]{\unskip\space`#1'}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lex}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{\lexAUX#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lexAUX}{mmm}{%
  \textit{#1}%
  \IfNoValueF{#2}{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}%
  \IfNoValueF{#3}{\tslt{#3}}%
}

\newcommand{\unor}[2]{\bracel\lex{#1}\kern3pt\symbol{"2194}\kern3pt\lex{#2}\}}
    
\begin{document}

Morpheme-based lexicalism must not posit a root illude. Instead it tries to 
account for the fact that all \textit{-ion} and \textit{-ive} Ns have a meaning 
retrievable from the corresponding V, when it is attested. “allowing a direct 
relationship” is unfortunate..ly an ad-hoc solution: why should a direct 
relationship be posited, while when the V is attested as in e.g.\@ attract 
attraction attractive, suggest suggestion suggestive,  prohibit prohibition 
prohibitive (all from example (3.32) in Haspelmath and Sims 2010, the V is 
supposed to be the common ancestor: \unor{attraction,n}{attractive,a}, 
\unor{suggestion,n}{suggestive,a}, \unor{prohibition,n}{prohibitive,a}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that it only works at the beginning of a paragraph. For a reason unknown to me, it won't work in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Do you mean that you want that *any* `\{` that happens to fall at the beginning of a line should be moved left? Possibly with suitable `microtype` protrusion parameters…

Comment: Yes, even when I create a customized curly bracket, it still does not start at the very beginning of a line. I use them for pairs of lexemes, so the content is large and may involve unbreakable spaces. In such conditions, the pair is very likely to fall at the beginning of a line. The shifted opening brace is really ugly.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Can you please add a short example of your situation?

Comment: I edited the original post, thanks.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Answer edited

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't understand how it works / the link with small caps.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Times New Roman (at least the one I have on my system) has no small caps, so I added a font substitution with TeX Gyre Termes.